# insert comment in the beginning of specified line in file

Tags: text-processing, sed

This is a pretty newbie question but what I am trying to do should be easy :(
I am developing a script to automatically install a development environment but I need to comment out `loadmodule` in the Apache configuration file on my Linux machine.

```
LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
```

I have been able to remove a comment with the following command:

```
sudo sed -i '66s/.//' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Answer (score 8):

Insert comment :

```
sed 's/^ *LoadModule/#&/' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Remove commment :

```
sed '/^ *# *LoadModule/s/#//' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Or to remove spaces too :

```
sed '/^ *# *LoadModule/s/^ *# *//' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

To apply substitution (insert or remove) just on a specific line number (not a good idea if you're trying to develop a script to perform automatic installation) :

```
# Apply on line 66 only
sed '66ba;p;d;:a /^ *# *LoadModule/s/^ *# *//' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Or (The same but with `-e` to make it portable to other `sed` too) :

```
sed -e '66ba' -e 'p;d;:a' -e ':a' -e '/^ *# *LoadModule/s/^ *# *//' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Or

```
sed '66{/^ *# *LoadModule/s/^ *# *//}' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

To edit just on a fixed line number without applying a match:

```
# Insert comment on line 66
sed '66s/^/#/' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

# Remove comment on line 66
sed '66s/^#//' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

# Remove spaces too
sed '66s/^ *# *//' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

---

Those will handle config file as :

(insert)

```
    LoadModule foo
LoadModule bar
```

(Remove):

```
    #LoadModule foo
#LoadModule bar

    #    LoadModule baz
#    LoadModule bax
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Vim as well:

```bsh
vim -c '/LoadModule/s/^/#/|x' httpd.conf
```